# Алгоритм аес

Tags: криптография

Здравствуйте!

Помогите решить проблему. Имеется программа которая реализует алгоритм АЕС, но есть некоторые различия:

1. время которое программе требуется на расшифрование в 2 раза больше чем то, которое требуется на зашифрование;
2. на разных компах результат работы программы различен, на одном компе после выполнения проги размер исходного и расшифрованного файлов одинаковы, а на другом компе они различаются в несколько байт.

В чем может быть причина? Ведь аес - это симметричный блочный шифр, а значит время, которое требуется на расшифрование файла, должно совпадать с временем, которое требуется на зашифрование файла или немного отличатся, но не в 2 раза ведь так. Почему на одном компе при расшифровании в расшифрованный файл записывается информация, равная той что в исходном файле, а на другом компе в расшифрованный файл к той информации, которая туда записывается, добавляются пустые строчки, в результате чего размер расшифрованного файла не совпадает с размер исходного файла.

Comment: 1. AES, а не AEC?
2. Очевидно, происходит это потому, что программа написана неправильно. Для решения проблемы, по возможности, желательно взять заведомо корректную реализацию, написанную и изученную криптографами-специалистами. Например, OpenSSL. Потому что в собственной реализации (если она не учебная, а предназначена для реальной работы) можно наделать ошибок. Даже, если данные будут шифроваться корректно, всегда остаются [атаки по сторонним каналам](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Атака_по_сторонним_каналам). Если задание учебное — код в студию, телепаты в отпуске.

Comment: Пустые строчки могут добавляться если на разных компах стоят разные оси(окна и юникс в данном случае), в винде символ перевода строки состоит из 2х символов а в никсах из одного. Вообщем всецело поддерживаю @drdaeman

Comment: если я выложу код вы сможете найти причину того почему различается время

Comment: если код писан на С, то скорее за все, у вас лажа с указателями. что приводит к непредсказуемому поведению программы

Comment: мой код написан на языке CUDA C

Comment: http://rghost.ru/42098530 - вот файл и кодом проги